# How to wait for a speech synthesis to complete

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement, voice

I'm writing a WP8.1 app, and am trying to output a voice in the following way:

```
using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    var voiceStream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("test 1");
    MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
    mediaElement.SetSource(voiceStream, voiceStream.ContentType);
    mediaElement.AutoPlay = false;
    mediaElement.Volume = 1;
    mediaElement.IsMuted = false;                                
    mediaElement.Play();
}
using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    var voiceStream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("test 2");
    MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
    mediaElement.SetSource(voiceStream, voiceStream.ContentType);
    mediaElement.AutoPlay = false;
    mediaElement.Volume = 1;
    mediaElement.IsMuted = false;                                
    mediaElement.Play();
}
```

And this does work... but it appears to be playing both at the same time - so it just sounds like an echo.  I can't see any way to wait the play to finish, or to be notified when it does - is there one?

Comment: Is there async version of `Play`? Or event? (I fail to find documentation of `MediaElement.Play()` method).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.play(v=win.10).aspx

Not as far as I can see

Comment: Check [MediaEnded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediaended.aspx) event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MediaElement has a MediaEnded event. You can use TaskCompletionSource to await it:

```
var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
mediaElement.MediaEnded += (o, e) => { tsc.TrySetResult(true); }
mediaElement.Play();

await tsc.Task;
```

(Please double check if the event get's fired even if the media playback is canceled somehow.)

Comment: BTW -- the mediaElement needs to be in the visual tree.  See [The Long Walk](http://pmichaels.net/2015/03/01/playing-media-in-windows-universal-apps/) blog with detail.